# Add equal spacing between flexed items

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to flex certain items which go up to two rows when a user selects more than 5 items, I am using the following code to flex the items inline, next to each other, I would like to add equal space between the icons, both horizontally and vertically:

```
 .items-to-flex{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    text-align: center !important;
    justify-content: center;
    }}
```

Comment: flex is only for one direction, so you can define the space vertically OR horizontally, if you need to have the same space on both axis you need grid for this.

Comment: if you're looking to space things out evenly across, rather than `justify-content: center;` I think you're looking more into `justify-content: around;` which will add that even margin for each item on the left and right,  or `justify-content: between;` which spaces out the items evenly without leftmost and rightmost margin.